# What is the difference between assign and put_session in Plug.Conn of the Phoenix Framework?

Tags: session, elixir, phoenix-framework

The documentation (https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html) names two functions that allow for storing a key-value pair in a `conn`

```
assign(conn, key, value)
```

> Assigns a value to a key in the connection

```
put_session(conn, key, value)
```

> Puts the specified value in the session for the given key

What is the difference between these two functions?

Answer (score 35):

Basically `assign` works only for particular connection - Plug.Conn structure - which means that this value would be gone with the end of the request - as conn will also dies - at the end of the request / response cycle.

Session lives longer and it's stored in cookies or in ets. Thanks to that you keep eg. data about the successfully logged in user across the requests.

TL;DR:

`assign` works for *each* request and it's wipe out after the end of the request cycle.

`put_session` inserts a value in the session and it's available until the session is cleared / expired.

Comment: The Plug documentation should really be updated with this level of detail, it would prevent a lot of confusion.

Comment: 5 years later, a PR. https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/pull/1102

Comment: That's really great news :)

Comment: Good documentation takes time.